# Enabling IIS 8.0 (windows 8 pro) Dynamic Compression

Tags: iis, windows-8, compression, iis-7.5, iis-8

Im having problems with compression under IIS 8 (Windows 8 Pro).

It works fine in Windows 7 under IIS 7.5 but in Windows 8 Pro It doesnt work.

After looking very deeply, I have compared the applicationHost config files (Windows 7 and Windows 8) and I found something interesting....

1. In Windows 7 I have inside applicationHost  under globalModules the tag `<add name="DynamicCompressionModule" image="%windir%\System32\inetsrv\compdyn.dll" />` and I found the file compdyn.dll inside System32\inetsrv
2. In Windows 8 I dont have that line in my applicationHost file  under globalModules and the compdyn.dll is missing inside System32\inetsrv

So actually Im sure that the issue, anyone know why Windows 8 Pro (IIS 8) doesnt come with that dll??

Is there something I have to do?

Thanks a lot and hope someone can help me.

**FIXED**

Simple Solution: Had to install the Dynamic Content Module for IIS and that's all.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have to install the feature on the Windows 8 Pro machine. From Start, type Programs and Features. Click on Turn Windows Features On or Off in the left hand column. Expand Internet Information Services/World Wide Web Services/Performance Features/. Place a checkmark by Dynamic Content Compression and click OK. The feature will be enabled and your site should work as long as all other features needed are installed.